# Sending Complex Objects to Controller with Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application where I am trying to submit the form through an ajax call while also passing in another complex object.  This means I am passing 2 complex objects back to the controller: the form data and an object array.  The problem is the form data makes it to the controller fine if I set the contentType to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but the object array comes over as null.  If I set the contentType to "application/json", the object array makes it to the controller just fine, but the form data is null.  So I think I basically need to convert the form data to a json object.  Here's what I've got:

ViewModel:

```
Public FOO foo
{
     public ObjectBar BarObject {get; set;}
     public string BarString {get; set;}
     // more properties
}
```

Controller:

```
[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult Submit(Foo viewModel, OtherObject[] dataSet)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

View:

```
// bunch of fields

<script>

    function submitForm(e) {
        debugger;
        var dataSets = getGridData();
        var form = $("#formName").serialize();
        var data = JSON.stringify({ viewModel: form, dataSet: dataSets }); //this is close, need to convert form data to json

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Report")',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
        });
    }

    //some more javascript stuff
</script>
```

Searching around stack overflow, it seems like all I need to do to convert the form data to json is something like

```
var jsonForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form));
```

but for some reason that is not working, even if I just try to pass just jsonForm to the controller witrh just the viewModel parameter.  Should I be using something else to convert, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from this answer in stack overflow:

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery?rq=1)

I found this statement:

$('form').serializeArray().map(function(x){this[x.name] = x.value; return this;}.bind({}))[0]

So I updated my code and wound up with this:

```
function submitForm(e) {
    debugger;
    var dataSets = getGridData();
    var form = $("#formName").serializeArray().map(function (x) { this[x.name] = x.value; return this; }.bind({}))[0];
    var data = JSON.stringify({ viewModel: form, dataSets: dataSets }); //this is close, need to convert form to json... now this works!


    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Report")',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        processData: true,
    });
```